# delete VSTS release previous attempts

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

one of our VSTS release is used for integration tests with helps of Visual Studio Test (C# test project).

Using Test project, allows us clean & easy integration failure detection and further out of the box alerts pushed to MS Teams.
[image]

those tests are triggered ideally every 1 hour and VSTS stores all attempts, after some month, the overall release definition starts to significatively slow down & even start failing to be triggered from outside (logicapp).

[image]

we don't care about historic attempt data and wiping out (either manually or with  a regular job) would do the trick. however we can't find any way to clean this, except creating a new release & delete the previous one.

But as our release are triggered from outside, creating a new release change the release ID + environment ID, making a flexible outside trigger (grab last release & last env) would be possible but clean up would be easier in our scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn’t such feature in VSTS release, you can vote this user voice: [Delete release attempts](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33372502-delete-release-attempts)